# Django can't display model.id in change form?

Tags: django, django-admin, admin

I have a model Post whose data I would like to display in model Favorite's Admin.

Post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="anonymous")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.id
```

Favorite model:

```
class Favorite(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, unique=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def get_post_nickname(self):
        return self.post.nickname
```

Favorite Admin:

```
class FavoriteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    #fields = ('user', 'get_post_nickname')
    list_display= ('user', 'post')

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.save()

admin.site.register(Favorite, FavoriteAdmin)
```

1. If I use the code as such, when I try to add a Favorite through its Admin I get the following error:

   > Caught TypeError while rendering: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found
2. OK so it doesn't like to display an Integer, so I thought I'll just display the nickname since its a Charfield. I uncommented the first line in FavoriteAdmin() to call FavoriteModel.get_post_nickname(). Now I get the following error:

> 'FavoriteAdmin.fields' refers to field 'get_post' that is missing from the form.

How can I solve both #1 and #2? Is it not possible to call a method in fields()? I thought it would be since list_display() accepts a method.

Comment: I think there's a bug with SO here. I definitely wrote `2. OK so it doesn't like to display an Integer,` but somehow the number "2" is displayed as "1" so there are two number "1"s. Weird.

Comment: In the list_display, what is get_post_id?

Comment: Oops sorry! I had changed it to just "post" but did not copy-paste correctly. My bad.

Comment: put a space before the quote that breaks up your ordered list to keep the numbering correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. I usually do this:

   ```
   class Post(models.Model):
       nickname = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="anonymous")

       def __unicode__(self):
           return u"%s" % self.id
   ```
2. Fields ([**`docs`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fields)) is how to control the layout of admin "add" and "change" pages. It wouldn't make sense for you to be able to include methods in a list of fields that aren't for just display. Hence list_display allows you to include methods.

Answer (score 1):

Python is expecting a unicode string, but in both instances you're feeding it something else.

In both instance a simple cast to a unicode string should fix the issue.

```
return unicode(self.id)
```

<strike>and</strike>

```
return unicode(self.post.nickname)
```

**edit:** You don't actually need to cast that part, sorry. Just the int cast to unicode should solve both problems.

Comment: also, you should probably change the default value to a unicode string as well. make it `u'anonymous'`

Comment: good point about the unicode, thank you. I actually pasted the wrong error msg for #2, sorry. It seems I am unable to call a method as a parameter of fields()?

Answer (score 1):

You've altered the post.`__unicode__`() routine to return an int!

[This is not a problem using the defaults.](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)

> A few special cases to note about list_display:
>
> If the field is a `ForeignKey`, Django will display the `__unicode__()` of
>   the related object.

Comment: Thanks for your anwers. Yup I know I changed the unicode to do so. I didn't think Django would be stumped by an int though...

Comment: I actually pasted the wrong error msg for #2, sorry. It seems I am unable to call a method as a parameter of fields()?